# Multiply matrix columns into a vector in Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen

I would like to multiply the columns of matrix A to vector v and finally get the sum of each column. I use Eigen library and coded as follows:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j< A.cols(); j++)
    C.col(j).noalias() = V.cwiseProduct(A.col(j));
V2 = C.colwise().sum();
```

However, it is still slow. 
I also used the following products but these are even slower.

```
1. C = A * V.asDiagonal();
2. C = A.array().rowwise() * V.transpose().array();
```

Any idea?

Comment: What compiler? What compiler flags (e.g. optimizations must be turned on)? How much time is 'slow' and on what hardware? [MCVE] please?

Comment: Thanks @AviGinsburg for your reply. The compiler is g++. The time is now about 0.03 sec and the size of matrix A is (38,000 , 160).

Answer (score 1):

Hm... what you're looking for is a plain standard vector-matrix product:

```
V2.noalias() = V.transpose() * A;
```

The `.noalias()` is optional, it's only here to save you one temporary.

If you really need the intermediate matrix `C`, then your two options should be equally fast as your hand-crafted for loop provided that you correct them to make them compute the same thing:

```
C = V.asDiagonal() * A;
C = A.array().colwise() * V.array();
```

And don't forget to enable compiler optimizations, e.g. `-O3 -march=native`.

Comment: Thanks @ggael. Yes, I need the intermediate matrix `C` for the rest of the code. Two options are faster than my hand-crafted for loop and in some other cases slower. The compiler optimization is enabled `03` but have no idea about `-march=native`. It seems it is the fastest way!